# urxvt uses pink instead of solarized until I run xrdb ~/.Xresources

Tags: ubuntu, colors, urxvt, ubuntu-13.04, solarized

Edit: I discovered, that this seems to be a bug in Ubuntu: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1163129 - Any idea how to fix this by myself?

I just want to switch to urxvt, but I have a strange problem with my `.Xresources`. When I log in and start urxvt, everything is pink in pink and I get these error messages

```
urxvt: unable to parse color 'S_base0', using pink instead.
urxvt: unable to parse color 'S_base03', using pink instead.
...(repeated for all colors I defined)...
urxvt: unable to parse color 'S_base03', using pink instead.
```

However, once I ran `xrdb ~/.Xresources`, all newly opened urxvt's are fine and beautifully solarized. WAT?

My .Xresources: https://gist.github.com/iGEL/6880992 - I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 (64 bit), but installed the package `rxvt-unicode-256color` from Ubuntu 13.10 to get the current version of urxvt (9.18).

Edit: Notice that the colors are defined in the same file they are used. Maybe urxvt (or whatever is reading the `.Xresources`) can't parse and use the variables in the same run? Looks however like an odd idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out: You have to remove the `-noccp` option in line 42 of `/usr/sbin/lightdm-session`, which prevents `xrdb` to use the preprocessor I needed.

Comment: Please vote on this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/1244578

Comment: I ran into a similar problem with gdm. In /etc/gdm/Xsession, removing the `-nocpp` flag from on the `xrdb -merge $userresources` line fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

If `~/.Xresources` are not processed with `cpp` when you login, you may want to save your original source as another name and rebuild `~/.Xresources` every time you make changes.

I just wrote a tool to automate this process: https://github.com/dolmen/Xresources.edit/

Answer (score 1):

Your `~/.Xresources` does not get read in automatically.

I suppose in Ubuntu (at least that's the case in debian) the resource file read in during the start of your X session is `.Xdefaults`.

To not break anything that depends (perhaps) on `~/.Xresources`, just make a symbolic link:

```
ln -s .Xresources ~/.Xdefaults
```

Start a new X session and the pink in pink should be gone.

Comment: That unfortunately didn't help, it's still pink. Also the `.Xresources` seems to be parsed, because the error messages originate from the `.Xresources`

Comment: @iGEL: That's a pity. I had exactly the same phenomenon (pink in pink), and the symbolic link fixed it. Unfortunately I don't have a Ubuntu machine to do further testing.

Comment: @iGEL: Perhaps you can check, if your `~/.xinitrc` contains a line similar to `test -r $HOME/.Xdefaults && xrdb -I$HOME -merge $HOME/.Xdefaults`

Comment: Thank you for your help, but after a little more googeling, I discovered that it seems to be a bug in Ubuntu :( https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1163129 - Sorry for not doing it properly before.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, less intrusive, instead of modifying `/usr/sbin/lightdm-session` is to change the *X session wrapper*.  This is my `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` for Ubuntu 12.04:

```
[SeatDefaults]
greeter-session=unity-greeter
allow-guest=false
greeter-hide-users=true
session-wrapper=/etc/X11/Xsession
```

Note the last line, which executes X11 sessions with the original Debian wrapper `/etc/X11/Xsession`.  It is a script very similar to `/usr/sbin/lightdm-session` but lets the `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/30x11-common_xresources` file do its thing.